# Class Destructor SEGFAULT

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, destructor, delete-operator

In my project I have two classes, the `EarleyParser` class:

```
class EarleyParser
{

    public:

        EarleyParser();
        virtual ~EarleyParser();

        void initialize( string filePath, bool probabilityParse );

    private:

        bool probabilityParser;

        typedef unordered_map< string, list<Production> > productionHashTable;
        productionHashTable earlyHashTable;

};
```

and the `Production` class:

```
class Production
{
    public:

        Production();

        Production( float productionProbability, int productionLength, vector< string >* productionContent );

        Production( const Production& copy_me );

        virtual ~Production();

        float getProductionProbability();
        int getProductionLength();
        vector< string >* getProductionContent();

    private:

        float productionProbability;
        int productionLength;
        vector< string >* productionContent;

        void setProductionProbability( float productionProbability );
        void setProductionLength( int productionLength );
        void setProductionContent( vector< string >* productionContent );

};
```

As you can see above the `EarlyParser` class has a member element that is an [`unordered_map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/unordered_map/), whose key element is a string and value is a [`list`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/) of elements from the `Production` class.

The code works correctly, and the `unordered_map` and `list` get populated, but when calling the standard destructor class of the `EarleyParser` I get a segmentation fault.

As I understand the default destructor of `EarleyParser` should call the default destructor of the `unordered_map` which should call the one of the `list` which should call for each of its elements the default destructor of the `Production` class, which is the following:

```
Production::~Production()
{
    if( this->productionContent != NULL )
        delete this->productionContent; <- line 44
}
```

Back tracing with Valgrind and GDB didn't give me much help on how to solve the segmentation fault, which is given exactly in the `EarleyParser.cpp` at the line 44 of destructor.

Should I implement the destructor class, or should the default destructor be ok?
Any ideas on what could be causing the segmentation fault?

**ADDED COPY CONSTRUCTOR**

```
Production::Production( const Production& copy_me )
{
    if( this->productionContent != NULL )
        this->productionContent = NULL;

    this->setProductionProbability( copy_me.productionProbability );
    this->setProductionLength( copy_me.productionLength );

    this->setProductionContent( copy_me.productionContent );

}
```

Comment: In your copy constructor, do you just copy the pointer or do you do a "deep" copy? And _why_ do you have a pointer to a container? Why not a reference instead?

Comment: What does the copy ctor of `Production` look like, and why are your destructors virtual? Also, does `Production` even *own* the `vector`? If yes, why is it a pointer, if no, why do you delete it?

Comment: `vector< string >* getProductionContent();` that makes me sick. Urgh pointer to container.

Comment: @Xeo - I added the copy constructor

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - I added the copy constructor

Comment: @TonyTheLion - I'm still a newbie, can you point me out the good way of doing?

Comment: @TonyTheLion - I compile with this option `std=c++0x`, so I believe yes...

Comment: Then you don't need a pointer to vector, the vector has move semantics, so will be moved from, when appropriate.  Which is the only reason I could think you used a pointer, to avoid a copy.  The move semantic will avoid unnecessary copy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Rule of Three is incomplete. Since you have a pointer member, you want to make sure have implemented the *copy constructor*, *copy assignment operator* and *destructor*.

Now, because you have a pointer to `vector` member, I'm going to tell you that you **shouldn't have that**, but instead just have a `std::vector<std::string>` or a `std::unique_ptr<std::vector<std::string> >`.

I don't know *why* you decided there was a need to hold a pointer to a container, but it's mostly not a good reason, and it's error prone.

You could hold a *reference* to a container, but you need to make sure it's initialized in the ctor.

The problem with pointers is that they are too easily grabbed for as a "solution" but in reality are extremely error prone and hard to use. If you *stopped thinking about pointers* and stopped being inclined to use them at every turn, you'd have a much easier time of it.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options.

1. Either you allocate a vector dynamically in `Production`, in which case you need an assignment operator to do a deep copy of the vector pointer. Your copy constructor should do the same. In this case, you should be following the [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29).
2. Or, you take a pointer to a vector in the `Production` constructor and do not perform a deep copy, in which case `Production` does not own the vector and should not delete it in the destructor.

If you have case 1, I suggest dropping the pointer and holding an `std::vector` by value.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not seeing any initialization of the productionContent variable.  Try initializing it to NULL with initializers.  Default values of uninitialized member variables are not null.

What this means is that productionContent != NULL  will always be true because of the fact that it starts out being something other than NULL.

Try something like this in all your constructors:

```
Production::Production( const Production& copy_me ) : productionContent(NULL)
{
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Any good or bad reason you have for a pointer, use a std::shared_ptr (as member and constructor parameter), the less you do the more you are. std::shared_ptr will make nullptr and deletion for you !